# Changing content in PDF file

Tags: php, css, pdf

Good day, I'm working with viewing of grades of the student. I have a print button that will print the grades of the student into PDF file. My question is how can I change the information inside the PDF file when the print file clicked? I just want to remove the navigation bar in that PDF file and other unnecessary information to it. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that once you've got a PDF it's really problematic to change it. However you can ensure you format the page correctly before printing to PDF.

For example you can have:

**print.css**

```
nav { display: none; }
```

and in the HTML head (somewhere):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

This is one of many ways to achieve this.

All rules defined in `print.css` will only be applied when printing.